# Error while Generating pdf and downloading from React native components

Tags: react-native, html-to-pdf

I have used react-native-html-to-pdf package for downloading React native page in pdf format. I have also added android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in AndroidManifest.xml file. But I'am still getting an error message as:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: RNHTMLtoPDF error: Could not create folder structure.
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the app again by npx react-native run-android? and make sure that you are requesting and checking the storage permission before performing the operation over it...

Comment: Yes. I have modified my code and it's working now. I have added user permissions to that. Now, everything works.
May I know how can I download the entire page in react native (view inside render) without adding any html template!

Comment: If you are supposed to show the HTML inside the view then you must have to use the HTML Viewer to show the content of URL or static HTML code inside your app.